# Silicon parabolic dispersion for X minima

Tags: electronic-band-theory, dispersion

I am constructing a minimal model of the silicon conduction band minima for a monte-carlo program. Assuming the six equivalent bands are parabolic and spherical, since the conduction band minima lie at 0.85$\Delta$, does the form then look like: $E(k) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m^*}(k-0.85\Delta)^2$?

I am confused about the implementation as the minima do not lie along $k=0$.

Comment: "Assuming the six equivalent bands are ... spherical" ... but they aren't. The energy rises more sharply in some directions than others.

Comment: It is a simplifying assumption that I make. However, what confuses me is this: if, with an electric field, I accelerate an electron $\hbar\dot{k}=eE$, and I plug the value of $k$ into the dispersion relation, because the minima are so far away from $k=0$, any electron will seemingly have a very high kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer. Since the velocity depends on $\nabla_kE(k)$, it does not matter where the parabola is centered.